# C++ - storing operator as char

Tags: c++, operators, char

weird que i know, but could something like the following be achived somehow?

```
int main (int argc, char * const argv[]) 
{
    const char* op1="+";
    int i = 10;
    int j = 20;
    int k = i op1 j; //compiler error, expected , or ; before op1

    printf("k is: %i", k);
}
```

Comment: Use an enum and a switch

Comment: This can actually be achieved by using closures:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4001582/c0x-closures-lambdas-example

Comment: @relaxxx: That's not "storing an operator as a char".

Comment: If the overall purpose of this is to be able to apply user-defined functions on your variables, consider embedding a scripting language in your program. If you want high performance, you could wrap those strings into proper .cpp files and get them compiled by g++ and link to them dynamically at run-time.

Comment: my answer (#define op1 +) was wrong, I misunderstood the question. I am sorry

Comment: @JasonHuntley thanks for that link, and everyone else

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sure, it's easy...

```
template <class T>
T execute_operator(T a, string op, T b)
{
    static unordered_map<string, function<T(T,T)>> operators =
    {
        { "+", [](T a, T b) { return a + b; } },
        { "-", [](T a, T b) { return a - b; } },
        etc
    };

    return operators[op](a,b);
};

int main (int argc, char * const argv[]) 
{
    const char* op1="+";
    int i = 10;
    int j = 20;
    int k = execute_operator(i,op1,j);

    printf("k is: %i", k);
}
```

Comment: That looks more like an unordered map.

Answer (score 4):

Not like that.

You need some way of parsing that string, and then switching to the relevant code based on the result.

You might also consider writing a bunch of functions:

```
int add(int x, int y) { return x+y; }
int sub(int x, int y) { return x-y; }
// etc.
```

and a typedef:

```
typedef int (*func)(int,int);
```

and then creating a `std::map<std::string,func>`, which would make the process of looking-up and calling the relevant function very easy.

Comment: The question did say `char`, even though the OP's example stored stuff in a `char*`. If it's just a char, there's no need to parse anything and you can use `switch` on the char itself.

Comment: @MrLister Even without parsing, having the map is more scalable than a `switch`.